How to put setter function as a parameter?
I need to rewrite the test so that the setter function is passed as a parameter. That is, inside the test, I create a valid book, take an invalid value from the parameter, take the function, and this function sets the invalid value in the required field of the book.
Test code:
@ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("provideInvalidFields")
  void saveBookShouldThrowsExceptionIfInvalidArguments(
      String field, String value, String errorMessage) throws Exception {
    var book = new Book();
    setField(book, field, value);
    var bookJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(book);

    mockMvc
        .perform(post("/api/v1/books").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(bookJson))
        .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
        .andExpect(
            jsonPath("$.errorMessage")
                .value("Failed to create a new book, the request contains invalid fields"))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.errors[0].field").value(field))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.errors[0].message").value(errorMessage));

    verify(libraryService, never()).addNewBook(book);
  }

setter function:
private static void setField(Book book, String field, String value) {
    switch (field) {
      case "name" -> {
        book.setName(value);
        book.setAuthor("Valid Author");
      }
      case "author" -> {
        book.setName("Valid Name");
        book.setAuthor(value);
      }
    }
  }

The method that passes parameters looks like this (I inserted a small piece because Stream is quite large):
private static Stream<Arguments> provideInvalidFields() {
    return Stream.of(
        Arguments.of(
            "name", "x", "Book name must be longer than 5 characters, shorter than 100 characters"),

I tried to review the theory of functional programming in Java, but nothing is sticking. It looks like I need to improve my knowledge of functional programming.

What if field isn't name or author? You should probably try running this with a debugger. I would prefer an immutable Book type. If you want to use a Factory or Builder I guess you could, but a record would seem more appropriate.

What are you actually trying to do here? This looks like a XY Problem to me. Do you want to test different Book instances with different fields? If so, why don't you provide those through the MethodSource directly?

@QBrute This test works correctly actually. But i want to refactor it using functional programming, i mean insteaf of:
var book = new Book();setField(book, field, value);
i want to put setter function as a parameter, so this function sets the invalid value in the required field of the book.

I fail to see the reason, why that's necessary. If it works, why do you need to refactor your code to make use of functional programming? Just for the sake of it?

Actually, it is not necessary. But i want to implement it just for practicing, but nothing comes to mind.

Practicing is fine, but as long as the code mutates state, it's hardly functional.

Take a look at the class Consumer<T>. This is the way to pass a setter as parameter.
